# prove that P Q R along with H(orthocentre) are collinear

Tags: geometry

> Let X be any point on the circumcircle of triangle ABC. Let the altitudes AD, BE, CF meet the circle again at D', E', F';if XD', XE', XF' cut BC, CA, AB at P,Q,R prove that P,Q,R are collinear with orthocentre H of triangle ABC and parallel to the pedal line of X

[Please see the figure I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm1yZ.jpg) 
I think that if we use converse of vertically opposite angle on PQRH then we can prove that it is straight line but I can't figure out how

Comment: Welcome to math SE! Please note that just stating the problem is not enough to gain favourable response or answer from the community. You are expected to show your thoughts and effort towards solving the problem. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34850/what-if-askers-dont-know-what-they-dont-know?cb=1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is it now ok @insipidintegrator actually its my first time using math SE so i dont know how to write questions

Comment: Yes it’s just about fine. Please familiarize yourself with mathjax so your problems are more readable: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjJk7P7or74AhVNplYBHbd3D-MQFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.meta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5020%2Fmathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt. By the way, what’s VOA?

Comment: sorry i meant voa for vertically opposite angle